# Creating a python module for my NMT model

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, keras

Good day everyone, I recently developed an NMT model for natural language translation. I want to code the NMT model, in python, which would be used for my web service. the code I have for the module so far, is incomplete. Please could you help me with it? Thank you
The code is written below:

```
def getModel():
    global model
    model= load_model('decoder_model.bin')
    model1 = load_model('encoder_model.bin')
    print("model is loaded")
print("loading keras model")
getModel()
```

`@app.route("\", methods = ["POST"])`

```
def predict():
    message = request.get_json(force = True)
    encoded = message = ["language"]
```

Comment: please post a running example with the error you receive .

Comment: Thank you skibee for your response . The code like I said is incomplete because I am a novice to deployment of NMT models to flask. This is like the backend for deployment using python and albeit I have watched videos, most of them dont have exactly the syntax, but this is what I could get from them so far. Sir please if you understand what I wrote, you can tell me to explain more. Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  For homework questions, please checkout the guidelines first - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. However, sir the videos I watch only few deal with neural networks, and none so far do the RNN, which I can use to get ideas for my own model, thats why I thought it was a good idea to ask here.